# prototype javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying out below code.

```
function Foo(who){
        this.me = who;
}
Foo.prototype.identify = function(){
     return "I am " + this.me;
};
var a1 = new Foo("a1");
a1.identify();
a1.identify = function(){
     alert("Hello, " + Foo.prototype.identify.call(this));
};
a1.identify();
```

Above code works well and I understand why Foo.prototype.identify.call was used.  I wanted to test my understanding of this so I changed a1.identify to below

```
a1.identify2 = function(){
     alert("Hello, " + a1.identify());
};
a1.identify2();
```

I expected above to work the same way. I am now just referring to identify by direct protocol chain. However, I get undefined when I run above. Am I missing something(or misunderstanding?).

Comment: I think your not calling the function u r just printing the function. It should be this `alert("Hello, " + a1.identify());` instead of  `alert("Hello, " + a1.identify);`

Comment: It's unclear what your question actually is.  There's nothing `undefined` in the code you have above.  You can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/94yLngj6/.  You probably meant to write `alert("Hello, " + a1.identify());` to actually run `a1.identify()` not to just print out the function itself, but when I run what you have above in the jsFiddle, nothing shows as `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, It is because I didn't have a1.identify() in alert OR not calling a1.identify2()().. thank you for making me realize this!!! Thank you both for quick answer.     hmmm, also, I was running this in the chrome developer tools and was giving me back undefined when I ran the code as I presented in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell what your question is.  When I run your code [in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/94yLngj6/), there's nothing `undefined` in it.  You are doing an `alert()` on `a1.identify` rather than `a1.identify()` so you weren't actually calling the function and I'm guessing that was one mistake of yours.  Instead `a1.identify` will just attempt to do a `.toString()` conversion on the method which will attempt to dump the source of the function (that's what my jsFiddle or your code shows).

So, probably, you meant to do this:

```
a1.identify2 = function(){
     alert("Hello, " + a1.identify());
     //         parens added here ^^
};
a1.identify2();
```

---

Perhaps what you may need explained is that these two can be somewhat different things:

```
Foo.prototype.identify
```

and

```
a1.identify
```

If nothing has been assigned directly to `a1.identify`, then executing `a1.identify()` will not find the `.identify` property directly on the `a1` object so it will then look on the `Foo.prototype` and it will find the property name there and execute that one on the prototype.

But, as soon as you do this:

```
a1.identify = function() {...}
```

Then, you've "overriden" this property.  Now, when you do:

```
a1.identify()
```

The JS interpreter finds your overriden property directly on the `a1` object and that is executed instead of the property that resides on the prototype.  When you do `obj.property`, the JS interpreter looks first for that property directly on the object and only if it's not found assigned directly to the object does it then search the object's prototype for a property with that name.

As you seem to know, you can always get to the function that's on the prototype, even if the property has been overriden directly on the object by going directly through the prototype with:

```
Foo.prototype.identify.call(a1)
```

So, you can override a prototype property for a specific instance and, even if you've overriden it, you can still get to the original property on the prototype if you need to or want to.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

```
a1.identify2 = function(){
 alert("Hello, " + a1.identify());
};
a1.identify2();
```

`a1.identify()` should have been called with `()`.

`a1.identify()` calls `alert()` and does not return any value. In such case, an undefined is returned. So, when `a1.identify2()` calls `a1.identify()`, `a1.identify()` is executed and undefined is returned. Hence, you see "Hello, undefined".

If you want to see output in `identify2()` then in `identify1()` instead of alerting, `return` the value.

Comment: Thank you for your help!